# Passing an object as query-params parameter in link-to

Tags: ember.js

Using the Route.transitionTo function, I can call,

```
this.transitionTo('posts', {queryParams: {sort: 'title'}});
```

So, say I have an object,

```
qpms={sort:'title'}
```

Now, I can make it,

```
this.transitionTo('posts',{queryParams:qpms});
```

I also know that, in the template,

```
{{#link-to 'posts' (query-params qpms)}}text{{/link-to}}
```

instead of,

```
{{#link-to 'posts' (query-params sort="title")}}text{{/link-to}}
```

won't work.
Is there some way to achieve the same effect as provided by the Route.transitionTo function, in the link-to helper??

So that in the posts controller, I can still get it as,

```
queryParams: ['sort'],
sort: null,
```

??

Comment: please placed more code, so that i can understand you clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you couldn't.

With current implementation of `query-params` helper you couldn't achieve it.

But you can create your own helper to work for.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d6d9969ff0355b090ddec8a34ea140ab)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you can use passing params to a like on Template

`{{#link-to 'posts'  qpms}}text{{/link-to}}`

Also you be sure that `qpms` must be define in `Controller` , `Route` or `Component`. like bellow

```
// Component
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    qpms: {sort: 'title'},
})
// Controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    qpms: {sort: 'title'},
})
```

OR 
`http://site/#/url/params/SORT`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params){
        return params;
    }
});
```

Note:: that above code it not necessary, Ember automatically return url params

Comment: your example is for dynamic segments and not query params

Comment: so you get the params from Route (URL)?